# How do I use D3DXVec3Unproject with D3D11?

Tags: c++, 3d, directx11, directx10, picking

I'm having a small issue with D3DXVec3Unproject. I'm currently using Direct3D 11 and not 10, and the signature for this function is:

```
D3DXVECTOR3 *pOut, CONST D3DXVECTOR3 *pV, CONST D3D10_VIEWPORT *pViewport,
      CONST D3DXMATRIX *pProjection, CONST D3DXMATRIX *pView, CONST D3DXMATRIX *pWorld
```

As you may have noticed, it requires a `D3D10_VIEWPORT`, and I'm using a Direct3D 11 viewport, `D3D11_VIEWPORT`.

Do you have any ideas how I can use D3DXVec3Unproject with Direct3D 11?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `D3DXVec3Unproject()` use [XMVector3Unproject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.transformation.xmvector3unproject). It accpet float parameters for viewport:

```
XMVECTOR XMVector3Unproject(
  [in]  XMVECTOR V,
  [in]  float ViewportX,
  [in]  float ViewportY,
  [in]  float ViewportWidth,
  [in]  float ViewportHeight,
  [in]  float ViewportMinZ,
  [in]  float ViewportMaxZ,
  [in]  XMMATRIX Projection,
  [in]  XMMATRIX View,
  [in]  XMMATRIX World
);
```

NOTE: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729728) you get some info about converting D3DXMath into DirectxMath.

Answer (score 2):

The structures are passive data, the only difference is that the D3D11 flavor deals with floats instead of integers for most of the fields.

If your quantities are integral, simply construct a corresponding `D3D10_VIEWPORT` and call the function.